# When I upload multi third-party jars packages, how to write a simple target path?

Tags: maven, repository, devops, artifactory

My local jar packages are all like this：

```
demo-1.0.0.jar
```

When I choose multiple deploy to upload my local jars to JFrog Artifactory, The target path I wrote always has various problems. My local jars all have the same groupId. I hope they can all be stored like this

```
groupId/artifactId/version/demo-version.jar
```

the jfrog artifactory Repository Layout rules:

```
[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]
```

How to write correct target path, when i choose multiple deploy?